# How to use mssql connection using ip/instance?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, tedious, tediousjs

I'm trying to connect to a production SQL Server instance but it fails to connect.

Could anyone help?

I'm grateful for the community's attention.

`.env`:

```
MSSQL_SERVER=ip/instance
MSSQL_PORT=1433
MSSQL_USER=sa
MSSQL_PASSWORD=password
MSSQL_DB_NAME=database
```

Error:

> Failed to connect to ip/instance:1433 - getaddrinfo
> ENOTFOUND ip/instance

adonisjs@lucid

```
mssql: {
      client: "mssql",
      connection: {
        user: Env.get("MSSQL_USER"),
        port: parseInt(Env.get("MSSQL_PORT")),
        server: Env.get("MSSQL_SERVER"),
        password: Env.get("MSSQL_PASSWORD", ""),
        database: Env.get("MSSQL_DB_NAME")
      },
      healthCheck: false,
      debug: false,
    },
```

Code:

```
Database.connection('mssql').from('dbo.EMP').select('*')
```

Comment: can you post code where you actually connect to the DB using these libraries?

Comment: adonisjs@lucid. updated the post

Comment: Did you try using a \ instead of a / (per https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/1364) for example "1.2.3.4\instanceName"

Comment: message": "Failed to connect to ip:undefined - self signed certificate",

Comment: for env you might need to escape it \\

Comment: Thank you. Its work with - options: {
          encrypt: false, // for azure
          trustServerCertificate: true, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. Its work with -

```
options: { encrypt: false, // for azure trustServerCertificate: true, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
```